# What regex to use for relative url?

Tags: regex, url

Good day.

What regex to use?

If relative url contains CompanyInfo.aspx - it rewrites to userfriendly url.

I mean

```
../CompanyInfo.aspx?id=404  -> http://mysite.com/company404
```

Comment: so you want it to drop 'Info.aspx?id=' and lowercase what's left?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('.*/(\w+)Info.aspx\?id=([\w]+)')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x8456058>
>>> p=_
>>> p.match('../CompanyInfo.aspx?id=404')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb74130f8>
>>> _.groups()
('Company', '404')
```

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: or for the community to improve upon... I'm going to sleep, g'nite.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '../CompanyInfo.aspx?id=404';
$str =~ s~\.\./(\w+)Info\.aspx\?id=(\d+)~'http://mysite.com/'.lc($1).$2~e;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
http://mysite.com/company404
```